# i can not find QString in PySide 1.1.0

Tags: python, qt, pyside, qstring

I want to use `QString` and `QStringList` but can not find them in `PySide 1.1.0` modules or documents. Not just `QString` and `QStringList`, I can not find `QTableModel`, `QListModel` etc. either.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

You don't need QString or QStringList: you can use Python's native types anywhere they would be needed in C++/Qt.

More details about this can be found [in PSEP 101](https://github.com/techtonik/pseps/blob/cf7430368098e1b9c87c2233dff8a00ef7059ad2/psep-0101.txt#L51).

For example,

- `QString` → `str` (`unicode` in Python 2)
- `QVariant` → whatever type
- `QByteArray` → `bytes` or `bytearray`

And there have never been such classes as `QTableModel` and `QListModel` in Qt.
You're probably looking for [`QAbstractTableModel`](http://www.pyside.org/docs/pyside/PySide/QtCore/QAbstractTableModel.html) and [`QAbstractListModel`](http://www.pyside.org/docs/pyside/PySide/QtCore/QAbstractListModel.html).

Comment: Is there an updated URL for the psep-0101 link? I can't seem to find this resource anywhere.

Comment: @barik Searching for `psep-0101` gives, for example, [**this result**](https://qt.gitorious.org/pyside/pseps/source/5a753a0f6b518b6a249ba5820fc05c450daf961c:psep-0101.txt).

Comment: Both psep-0101.html links (in the answer and in the comment) are broken.